# Please Guide Php Code for Ajax Connection

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, asp.net-ajax, pos

AOA,
I'm taking course "Create POS System - Inventory & sales with PHP 7 & adminLTE"
But i'm creating as CMS "Cost Management System"
by taking lectures i done user management & add my users but now i'm stuck in edit lecture, i'm doing exactly same what he is doing in video,
Please Someone help me now as I'm sharing you my code,

File is Users.js

[Users.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50XSh.png)

```
/*=============================================
EDITING USER
=============================================*/
$(document).on("click", ".btnEditUser", function(){

    var idUser = $(this).attr("idUser");
    console.log("idUser", idUser);

    var dataForm = new FormData();
    dataForm.append("idUser", idUser);

    $.ajax({

        url: "ajax/users.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: dataForm,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(answer){
            
            console.log("answer", answer);

        }

    });

 });
```

Next File is users.ajax.php

[Users.ajax.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObWFk.png)

```
     <?php

 require_once "../Controllers/User.Controller.php";
 require_once "../Modules/User.Modules.php";
class AjaxUsers{

    /*=============================================
    EDIT USER
    =============================================*/

    public $idUser;

    public function ajaxEditUser(){

        $item= "id";
        $value = $this->idUser;

        $answer = UserController::ctrShowUsers($item, $value);

        echo json_encode($answer);
    }


    

/*=============================================
EDIT USER
=============================================*/

if (isset($_POST["idUser"])) {

    $edit = new AjaxUsers();
    $edit -> idUser = $_POST["idUser"];
    $edit -> ajaxEditUser();
}
```

Please Guide console.log("answer", answer); isn't display anything in my chrome.. after cleaning cache too

console.log("answer", answer); isn't display anything in my chrome..

[image]

Comment: If you call the PHP from for example POSTMAN does it echo anything? You need to add error handling in your ajax and turn on error reporting in the PHP - so start with `success: function(answer){ console.log("answer", answer);}, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}`

Comment: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at jquery.min.js:2
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2) 

this is new error

Comment: Now click F12, go to the network tab, run the script and then look at the response from the PHP. Likely a 404 HTML page which means you need to play around with `url: "ajax/users.ajax.php",`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in D:\xampp\htdocs\Cost\ajax\users.ajax.php on line 31

Comment: if (isset($_POST["idUser"])) {

    $edit = new AjaxUsers();
    $edit -> idUser = $_POST["idUser"];
    $edit -> ajaxEditUser();
}

Error in if (isset($_POST["idUser"]))  ???

Comment: I cannot read that. Update the question with relevant errors